# Why is there still background after transition?

Tags: css

I'm made this button that when hovered transitions the ::before in to change how the button looks. It works fine when there is no border but when a border is added it leaves a little bit of the background.

```css
.submit-button {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: red;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
        transition: color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.8, 1);
        border-radius: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
         position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .submit-button::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 24px;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: left;
        transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.8, 1);
    }

    .submit-button:hover::before {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }

    .log-out-button:hover {
        color: red
    }
    
    div {
      background-color: red
    }
```

```html
<div><button class="submit-button log-out-button">hello</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different look but you could simplify your CSS and solve your border radius problem by depending on the `overflow: hidden` styling and having the background color of your transform fill the space of the shape (essentially falling behind the border).

```css
.submit-button {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: red;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 4px;
    }

    .submit-button::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: left;
        transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.8, 1);
    }

    .submit-button:hover::before {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }

    .log-out-button:hover {
        color: red
    }
    
    div {
      background-color: red
    }
```

```html
<div><button class="submit-button log-out-button">hello</button></div>
```